# If Kafka Consumer fails (Spark Job), how to fetch the last offset committed by Kafka Consumer. (Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Before I give any details, please note, I am **NOT** asking how to fetch the latest offset from Console using kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker.

I am trying to make a kafka consumer (kafka version 0.10) in Spark (2.3.1) using Scala (2.11.8), which will be fault tolerant. By fault tolerant, I mean, if for some reason the kafka consumer dies and restarts, it should resume consuming the messages from the last offset.

For achieving this, I commit the Kafka offset once it has been consumed using the below code,

```
    val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
"bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
"key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
"value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
"group.id" -> "group_101",
"auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
"enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean), /*because messages successfully polled by the consumer may not yet have resulted in a Spark output operation*/
"session.timeout.ms" -> (30000: java.lang.Integer),
"heartbeat.interval.ms" -> (3000: java.lang.Integer)
)

val topic = Array("topic_1")

val offsets = Map(new org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition("kafka_cdc_1", 0) -> 2L) /*Edit: Added code to fetch offset*/

val kstream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
ssc,
PreferConsistent,
Subscribe[String, String](topic, kafkaParams, offsets)  /*Edit: Added offset*/ 
)

kstream.foreachRDD{ rdd =>
val offsetRange = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
if(!rdd.isEmpty()) {
  val rawRdd = rdd.map(record => 
 (record.key(),record.value())).map(_._2).toDS()
  val df = spark.read.schema(tabSchema).json(rawRdd)
  df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_tab")
  df.write.insertInto("hive_table")
}
kstream.asInstanceOf[CanCommitOffsets].commitAsync(offsetRange) /*Doing Async Commit Here */
}
```

I have tried many thing to fetch the latest Offset for the given topic, but could not get it to work.

Can anyone help me out with the scala code to achieve this, please?

**Edit:**
In the above code, I am trying to fetch the last offset by using

```
val offsets = Map(new org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition("kafka_cdc_1", 0) -> 2L) /*Edit: Added code to fetch offset*/
```

but the offset fetched by the above code is 0, not the latest. Is there anyway to fetch the latest offset?

Comment: I see you have sufficient code to take care of this. Can you post what error or issue you are seeing?

Comment: @AbhishekN I have edited the question to add the code I am using to fetch the last offset. But somehow, I always end up with the offset 0 being fetched by using this method. I would like to fetch the last offset. Are you aware of any way this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to the above issue. Here it is. Hope it helps someone in need.

**Language: Scala, Spark Job**

```
val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
"bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
"key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
"value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
"group.id" -> "group_101",
"auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
"enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean), /*because messages successfully polled by the consumer may not yet have resulted in a Spark output operation*/
"session.timeout.ms" -> (30000: java.lang.Integer),
"heartbeat.interval.ms" -> (3000: java.lang.Integer)
)

import java.util.Properties

//create a new properties object with Kafaka Parameters as done previously. Note: Both needs to be present. We will use the proprty object just to fetch the last offset

val kafka_props = new Properties()
kafka_props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
kafka_props.put("key.deserializer",classOf[StringDeserializer])
kafka_props.put("value.deserializer",classOf[StringDeserializer])
kafka_props.put("group.id","group_101")
kafka_props.put("auto.offset.reset","latest")
kafka_props.put("enable.auto.commit",(false: java.lang.Boolean))
kafka_props.put("session.timeout.ms",(30000: java.lang.Integer))
kafka_props.put("heartbeat.interval.ms",(3000: java.lang.Integer))

val topic = Array("topic_1")

/*val offsets = Map(new org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition("topic_1", 0) -> 2L) Edit: Added code to fetch offset*/

val topicAndPartition = new org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition("topic_1", 0) //Using 0 as the partition because this topic does not have any partitions
val consumer = new KafkaConsumer[String,String](kafka_props)    //create a 2nd consumer to fetch last offset
import java.util
consumer.subscribe(util.Arrays.asList("topic_1"))   //Subscribe to the 2nd consumer. Without this step, the offsetAndMetadata can't be fetched.
val offsetAndMetadata = consumer.committed(topicAndPartition)    //Find last committed offset for the given topicAndPartition
val endOffset = offsetAndMetadata.offset().toLong   //fetch the last committed offset from offsetAndMetadata and cast it to Long data type.

val fetch_from_offset = Map(new org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition("topic_1", 0) -> endOffset) // create a Map with data type (TopicPartition, Long)

val kstream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
ssc,
PreferConsistent,
Subscribe[String, String](topic, kafkaParams, fetch_from_offset) //Pass the offset Map of datatype (TopicPartition, Long) created eariler
)

kstream.foreachRDD{ rdd =>
val offsetRange = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
if(!rdd.isEmpty()) {
  val rawRdd = rdd.map(record => 
 (record.key(),record.value())).map(_._2).toDS()
  val df = spark.read.schema(tabSchema).json(rawRdd)
  df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_tab")
  df.write.insertInto("hive_table")
}
kstream.asInstanceOf[CanCommitOffsets].commitAsync(offsetRange) /*Doing Async offset Commit Here */
}
```